# star ratings hover independent for each star rating

Tags: html, css

I am having a weird issue when i have one star rating the code works really fine but the problem is when i add another star rating. the second star rating is connected with the first star rating (each change i make to the second one appears in the first). i want to know how to fix this error and make each star rating independent
    html code

```
<fieldset class="rating">
    <legend>Please rate:</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
<label for="star5" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" />
<label for="star4" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" />
<label for="star3" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" />
<label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" />
<label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
</fieldset>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
<fieldset class="rating">
    <legend>Please rate:</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
</fieldset>
```

CSS code

```
.rating {
    float:left;
}

/* :not(:checked) is a filter, so that browsers that don’t support :checked don’t 
   follow these rules. Every browser that supports :checked also supports :not(), so
   it doesn’t make the test unnecessarily selective */
.rating:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
    clip:rect(0,0,0,0);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label {
    float:right;
    width:1em;
    padding:0 .1em;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:200%;
    line-height:1.2;
    color:#ddd;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #bbb, 2px 2px #666, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label:before {
    content: '★ ';
}

.rating > input:checked ~ label {
    color: #f70;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #c60, 2px 2px #940, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
    color: gold;
    text-shadow:1px 1px goldenrod, 2px 2px #B57340, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating > input:checked + label:hover,
.rating > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
    color: #ea0;
    text-shadow:1px 1px goldenrod, 2px 2px #B57340, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating > label:active {
    position:relative;
    top:2px;
    left:2px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this:

```css
div.stars {

  width: 270px;

  display: inline-block;

}

 

input.star { display: none; }

 

label.star {

  float: right;

  padding: 10px;

  font-size: 36px;

  color: #444;

  transition: all .2s;

}

 

input.star:checked ~ label.star:before {

  content: '\f005';

  color: #FD4;

  transition: all .25s;

}

 
input.star-5:checked ~ label.star:before {

  color: #FE7;

  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;

}

 

input.star-1:checked ~ label.star:before { color: #F62; }

 

label.star:hover { transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3); }

 

label.star:before {

  content: '\f006';

  font-family: FontAwesome;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="stars">

  <form action="">

    <input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star"/>

    <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>

    <input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star"/>

    <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>

    <input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star"/>

    <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>

    <input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star"/>

    <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>

    <input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star"/>

    <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>

  </form>

</div>


<br > <br >

<div class="stars">

  <form action="">

    <input class="star star-5" id="star-6" type="radio" name="star"/>

    <label class="star star-5" for="star-6"></label>

    <input class="star star-4" id="star-7" type="radio" name="star"/>

    <label class="star star-4" for="star-7"></label>

    <input class="star star-3" id="star-8" type="radio" name="star"/>

    <label class="star star-3" for="star-8"></label>

    <input class="star star-2" id="star-9" type="radio" name="star"/>

    <label class="star star-2" for="star-9"></label>

    <input class="star star-1" id="star-10" type="radio" name="star"/>

    <label class="star star-1" for="star-10"></label>

  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much... would you tell me what was making the error in my code ?

Comment: please mark it as answer, look at `id=star-n` this `n` started from 1-10

Comment: I got what u mean and I update what u have said in my code as I need the same design, But I still have a problem as when I rate the second star rate the hover disappear from the first one.